# Error running label_image with output_layer=pool_3

Tags: tensorflow

The tensorflow exercise in the image recognition tutorial suggests running the c++ example with 
`--output_layer=pool_3`. I have tried running this and am getting an error:

```sh
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image --output_layer=pool_3

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:40] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 4
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:58] Direct session inter op parallelism threads: 4
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0x558ae6a5d210 Compute status: Invalid argument: input must be 2-dimensional
     [[Node: top_k = TopK[T=DT_FLOAT, k=5, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const/_0)]]
E tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:311] Running print failed: Invalid argument: input must be 2-dimensional
     [[Node: top_k = TopK[T=DT_FLOAT, k=5, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const/_0)]]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the TensorFlow code in the [image recognition tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html) requires additional modification before the `--output_layer=pool_3` option will work:

> One can specify this by setting `--output_layer=pool_3` in the C++ API example and then **changing the output tensor handling**.

To change the output tensor handling, you will need to modify the code [below this line in `label_image/main.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2bde1e1308767ca240422596143832cbb095196b/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc#L308). The [`PrintTopLabels()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2bde1e1308767ca240422596143832cbb095196b/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc#L208) function calls [`GetTopLabels()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2bde1e1308767ca240422596143832cbb095196b/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc#L183), which takes a single 2-D (batch x classes) tensor—assumed to be the output of a [`tf.nn.softmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax) containing a probability distribution for the labels in a batch of images—and builds a small TensorFlow graph using the [`tf.nn.top_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#top_k) op . The `pool_3` layer outputs a four-dimensional (batch x height x width x depth) tensor, which will require additional processing.

The additional processing has been left as an exercise for the reader. However, there are some things you could try:

- Reshape the output into a two-dimensional (batch x features) matrix, and train a fully connected layer (or more) to recognize features in your own training data.
- Visualize the output of the pooling layer by slicing it along the depth dimension, and encoding the slices into images using the  [`tf.image.encode_png()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/image.html#encode_png) op.

**N.B.** Since the documentation is better, I've provided links to the Python documentation, rather than the corresponding C++ API. You might find it (much!) easier to modify the [Python code for Inception inference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2bde1e1308767ca240422596143832cbb095196b/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py) instead.